# JavaScript - drawing on .svg diagram image

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawing

Let's say I have a very simplified diagram as below in .svg format:
[Map 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNedG.png)
(In reality the image will be much more complex and will)

What I would like to achieve is to write a JavasScript program that draws a bubble with some text on each subsequent square every 10 seconds as shown in the following image:
[Map 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uycpO.png)

Then on click of the bubble I would like to display some more info in a form of a popup.

So, in principle I need to get coordinates of each of the rectangles. Set up a timer. And and draw the bubble.

But what is the best way of achieving it? Just use HTML5 Canvas? Or some libraries like D3.JS? Or some other technology like GeoJSON?

I am expecting some guidance or sample code.

Comment: Please change the question title so that it is more specific

Comment: As it is, it's difficult to answer your question, since it seems to be off-topic (looking for recommendations), and might lead to opinionated answers. For what it's worth, you might be able to do it with plain Javascript, though it depends on the complexity of your actual SVG's structure.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a high-level library that builds on the HTML5 Canvas API; you can find some canvas libraries at https://github.com/raphamorim/awesome-canvas that you can use; the exact code will differ based on the library you choose.